# how to apply forEach method on array object

Tags: javascript, foreach

Its from a book called eloquent JavaScript, but I get the uncaught reference error and can't figure out what the problem is. I am new to programming and someone advised me to read this book.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>js</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            sum = 0;
        forEach(numbers, function(number) {
            sum += number;
        });
        console.log(sum);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In that chapter's example, it creates a function called `forEach()`, which you've failed to do. http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html

Comment: i just copied the code and it should have worked

Comment: Well did you follow along and do the code directly above it? There's only a single sentence in between, so it would be sort of silly for the book to write out that same exact function again.

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` is `Array` method not global function

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    sum = 0;

numbers.forEach(function(number) {
  sum += number;
});

console.log(sum);
```

**Update:**

in your case, you forgot copy [function declaration for forEach.](http://goo.gl/AoQWd9)

Answer (score 1):

forEach is not a global function, you would have to use Array.forEach method to loop through your array object.

Answer (score 0):

you have got your ForEach method wrong.You have to give forEach a callback function and you can give it three parameters which indicates the elements,their index and the array itself.ForEach method is a method of Array.prototype object.[read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) That means it works on the array object itself .Objects inherit from its prototype.

if we have an object ,say

```
function Obj(){};
```

and a method added to the prototype of this objec

```
Obj.protoype.add=function(){};
```

if we create a new instance ,to get the add method for its prototype method we have to call the object's name then use dot notation to get this method executed

```
var newObj=new Obj();
newObj.add();
```

in your case to get the foreach method for your number array you have to do the same.This applies to other array methods like map,every,some etc.

```js
 var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
           var  sum = 0;
        numbers.forEach(function(elements,index,array){
     sum+=elements;
  })
  document.write(sum);
```